# How to create this selection with JS or TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tinymce

I need to create a selection with native JS or TinyMCE methods.

Currently I have this code that does what is shown in the image below:

```
const table = editor.dom.getParent(editor.selection.getNode(), 'table');
if (table) {
    editor.selection.select(table);
}
```

I have also tried to do this and it turns out the same as above:

```
const table = editor.dom.getParent(editor.selection.getNode(), 'table');
if (table) {
    const rng = editor.dom.createRng();
    rng.selectNode(table);
    editor.selection.setRng(rng);
}
```

[Result image I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRT7l.png)

I need to make this type of selection (this selection is with the mouse):

[Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DL0O.png)